# Can we always construct a "$p$th root" of a $p$-element in a finite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p$ be a prime, $G$ a finite group, and $g\in G$ a $p$-element.
Can one always embed $G$ in a finite group $H$ that contains a $p$-element $h$ such that $h^p=g$?

Comment: What's a $p$-element?

Comment: @user26857 For a prime $p$, a $p$-element of a group is an element whose order is a power of $p$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks. (I could have find it by myself, but the intention was to suggest the OP to include this definition in the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of some symmetric group $S_n$, so we can assume $G=S_n$. If we embed $S_n$ into $S_n^p=S_n\times\dots\times S_n$ by sending $\sigma$ to $(\sigma,\dots,\sigma)$, and then embed that into $S_{pn}$ in the obvious way, then every element of $S_n$ has a $p$th root in $S_{pn}$, since the product of $p$ disjoint $k$-cycles is the $p$th power of a $pk$-cycle.